# Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '' in angular 7

Tags: angular, routes

I want to use `routerLink` in angular 7 app.

**app.routingts.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [  
{
  path: '',
  component: AdminComponent,
  children: [     
    { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },
    { path: 'drivers', loadChildren: './drivers/drivers.module#DriversModule' }
  ]
 }
];
```

**admin html**

```html
<app-nav></app-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**dashboard html**

```html
<app-nav></app-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**HTML from nav component**

```html
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/drivers']">Drivers<span class="sr-only">
```

[image: Folder]

**Error**

```
core.js:1449 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'drivers'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'drivers'
```

Comment: You could turn on route tracing to see if that provides any indication of the issue. As the second argument to the `forRoot` method specify: `{ enableTracing: true }`

Comment: Can you provide information on what your valid Urls should look like? Should it just be `drivers`? If so, then what should be displayed in your second router outlet?

Comment: Valid URL should be : localhost:4200/admin/drivers

Comment: Then the first path should be: `path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent,`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Try this**

**Adminrouting**

```
 const routes: Routes = [  
 {
  path: '',    
  component: AdminComponent,
  children: [
    { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },
    { path: 'drivers', loadChildren: './drivers/drivers.module#DriversModule' },
  ]
 }
];
```

**HTML**

```
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['drivers']">Drivers<span class="sr-only">
```

**admin.component.html**

```
<app-nav></app-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.routing**

```
{ path: 'admin' , loadChildren:'./admin/admin.module#AdminModule'},
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to have router configuration like this

```
const routes: Routes = [  
{
  path: 'admin',
  component: AdminComponent,
  children: [     
    { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },
    { path: 'drivers', loadChildren: './drivers/drivers.module#DriversModule' }
  ]
 },
{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: 'admin',
  pathMatch: 'full'
}
];
```

Template:

```
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['admin/drivers']">Drivers<span class="sr-only">
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, Let me try

Comment: Now it shows 
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'dashboard/admin/drivers'

Comment: what is the dashboard. can you please create stackblitz. will help to fix it.

Comment: because I have put <app-nav> in dashboard component. And tried to navigate on page.

Comment: the solution worked for me. I guess it is b'cs  'empty' path. once the empty path is redirect and first level path have a tag, it works.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to achieve a URL like this: `localhost:4200/admin/drivers`

Then your path should look like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [  
{
  path: 'admin',
  component: AdminComponent,
  children: [     
    { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },
    { path: 'drivers', loadChildren: './drivers/drivers.module#DriversModule' }
  ]
 }
];
```

And your link should either be this:

```
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/admin/drivers']">Drivers<span class="sr-only">
```

For an absolute route or this:

```
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['drivers']">Drivers<span class="sr-only">
```

for a relative route. (No slash)

Answer (score 0):

When you use routerLink with the property binding syntax, like this: [routerLink], then it should be assigned a name of the property the value of which will be the route it should navigate the user to.
So to fix your issue, replace this routerLink="['/drivers']" with routerLink="/drivers" in your HTML.

```
HTML
<a class="nav-link" routerLink="/drivers">Drivers<span class="sr-only">
```